# Calculator with 3+ values

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and have been making the good old Calculator. I have gone forward from a 2 value calculator to a 3 value calculator and wondered.. How is it possible to make a 10 digit calculator (purely using +,-,*,/) that doesn't forever to code.. I have a if statement which returns what happens if the operators are + and + or + and - etc.. and if i was to go to 4 value, i would be writing 64 ifs, and 5 value would be 256 if statements.

Is there a way to change this such that it wouldn't require writing out so many if statements?

Here is my the important parts of the code:

Calculator.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "headers.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int nInput1 = GetUserInput();
char chOperation = GetMathematicalOperation();
{
    if (chOperation == '=')
    {
        cout << "The answer is: " << nInput1 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
int nInput2 = GetUserInput();
char chOperation2 = GetMathematicalOperation();
{
    if (chOperation2 == '=')
    {
        int nResult = CalculateResult(nInput1, chOperation, nInput2);
        cout << "The answer is: " << nResult << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

int nInput3 = GetUserInput();

int nResult = CalculateResult2(nInput1, chOperation, nInput2, chOperation2, nInput3);

PrintResult(nResult);
}
```

CalculateResult.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int CalculateResult(int nX, char chOperation, int nY)
{
if (chOperation == '+')
    return nX + nY;
if (chOperation == '-')
    return nX - nY;
if (chOperation == '*')
    return nX * nY;
if (chOperation == '/')
    return nX / nY;

return 0;
}
```

GetMathematicalOperation.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char GetMathematicalOperation()
{
cout << "Please enter an operator (+,-,*,/ or =): ";

char chOperation;
cin >> chOperation;
return chOperation;
}
```

CalculateResult2.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int CalculateResult2(int nX, char chOperation, int nY, char chOperation2, int nZ)
{
if (chOperation == '+' && chOperation2 == '+')
    return nX + nY + nZ;
if (chOperation == '+' && chOperation2 == '-')
    return nX + nY - nZ;
if (chOperation == '+' && chOperation2 == '*')
    return nX + nY * nZ;
if (chOperation == '+' && chOperation2 == '/')
    return nX + nY / nZ;

if (chOperation == '-' && chOperation2 == '+')
    return nX - nY + nZ;
if (chOperation == '-' && chOperation2 == '-')
    return nX - nY - nZ;
if (chOperation == '-' && chOperation2 == '*')
    return nX - nY * nZ;
if (chOperation == '-' && chOperation2 == '/')
    return nX - nY / nZ;

if (chOperation == '*' && chOperation2 == '+')
    return nX * nY + nZ;
if (chOperation == '*' && chOperation2 == '-')
    return nX * nY - nZ;
if (chOperation == '*' && chOperation2 == '*')
    return nX * nY * nZ;
if (chOperation == '*' && chOperation2 == '/')
    return nX * nY / nZ;

if (chOperation == '/' && chOperation2 == '+')
    return nX / nY + nZ;
if (chOperation == '/' && chOperation2 == '-')
    return nX / nY - nZ;
if (chOperation == '/' && chOperation2 == '*')
    return nX / nY * nZ;
if (chOperation == '/' && chOperation2 == '/')
    return nX / nY / nZ;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look into translating your formula into a tree structure and traversing it. Google infix traversal for more info.

Comment: Seems like a good conceptual design question to me, even if it happens to already include some code.  The question isn't "How do I fix this code?"  It's, "How do I design a calculator without tons of if statements?  This is what I've tried so far."

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Community seems to agree. I'll leave as is.

Comment: @Frost Engineer The code works fine (except if you enter something wrong it goes funny, but i'm not that good yet so haven't added anything to 'redo' a question if entered something wrong).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Programming is all about data structures and algorithms. In your
example, there is no apparent data strcture: your functions are
working with raw user input and directly provide the answer, without
introducing any *intermediary structure* to represent the logic of
the computation.

As a practical consequence of the well-known equation

```
programs = data structures + algorithms
```

the absence of adequate *data structure* forces you to represent
the logic of the computation in the *algorithms* part, that is,
in your code. This is why your code looks so complicated, with that
large number of `if`s.  And your instinct is right, whenever your
code looks complicated, it shall ring a bell yelling *there is
something wrong* and that *something* is typically that you are using
the wrong data structure.

The abstraction you are missing here is what is called an *algebraic
expression,* which you can think of as an unevaluated expression.  So
now, I will answer your question on how to write your calculator—but I
strongly suggest you change the problem instead, and write another
type of calculator.

Here are the steps to write a calculator supporting arbitrarily
complicated expressions:

1. Implement [Binary expression trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) as an abstract class
   `Expression` having two concrete descendants, one `Leaf` for the
   numbers (leaves) and one other `Node` for the operations (nodes).
2. Follow the so called [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to write an evaluator for
   your expressions. You want to write an evaluator taking an
   `Expression` and evaluating it, the *Visitor pattern* is the common
   way to tell if the `Expression` is actually a `Leaf` or a `Node`.
3. Write a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) to transform user input into an
   expression. This is a tedious task, but there is automatic tools to
   help you there, such as [Bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison).

If you are a beginner, these three steps are challenging because they
will expose you to many new concepts of programming simultaneously:
abstract data structures, input/output and parsers.
A much more tractable exercise
is to write a *reverse polish notation (RPN) calculator:* with such a
calculator, instead of telling the
computer to compute `3 + 4 * 5` you tell it to compute `4 5 * 3 +`
which greatly simplifies the logic of the program:

1. Instead of working with binary expression trees and thus with
   abstract and concrete classes, you only work with a stack of
   numbers: the data structure used is much simpler.
2. Because of 1., there is no need to use the contorted visitor
   pattern.
3. Reading input and evaluate it is much easier in RPN
   than in the usual infix notation, because there is no need
   to pay attention to priority rules.

Once you are satisfied with your example, you can look for the program
`bc(1)` on a Linux box, it is a complete reverse polish notation
calculator, you may want to study its features or its code (in C) to
find more challenges!

Comment: Actually, its `dc(1)` that is the RPN calculator... and `bc(1)` was originally implemented as an infix to RPN compiler coupled with dc (you send `5 + 4` to bc and bc would send `5 4 +` to dc and return the results - ref: http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Bc ).

Answer (score 7):

Probably what you want to try first is an [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) calculator.  With RPN, you push the numbers onto a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29), then pop them off when someone enters an operator.  It's easier to implement than an infix calculator, but lets you write arbitrarily long expressions and evaluate them as you go along.

The next step would be to use the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to convert an infix expression into an RPN expression.  It's too long to include the details here, but it is a well-known algorithm.

The next step would be to write a full expression [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser#Parser), which is quite an advanced topic, but extremely flexible and useful.  There are many tools available to help you do this.

Either way, you probably want to do some research on stacks, queues and trees, and maybe try out a couple test programs using a stack before tackling a calculator again.  C++ has a [stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/stack/) implementation in its standard library that would be a good starting point to learn.